# How to check if a transaction has completed correctly or has been rejected by some assert check

Tags: nethereum, c#, error

We have developed a simple Smart Contract which offers this following public transaction method:

```
function bid(uint256 _userCode, uint256 _amount) public {

        assert(_userCode> 0);
        assert(_amount> 0);

        winningBid.userCode= _userCode;
        winningBid.amount= _amount;

        var bidData= Bid(_userCode, _amount);
        bids.push(bidData);
    }
```

We are sending the transaction using this Nethereum code:

```
var result = bidFunction.SendTransactionAndWaitForReceiptAsync(address, gas, balance, null, userCode, amount).Result;
```

The method invocation does not throw any exception, even passing `0` to the `userCode` that, if you take a look to the Smart Contract, should trigger the assert and stop the method execution.

How could we check if a transaction has completed correctly or has been rejected by some assert check?

Comment: Does the function  include a parameter for a callback function? This is usually how it is done.

Comment: We are not using any callback function. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Since byzantinum the recipt includes a field status to indicate if the transaction was executed correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [Solidity docs on error handling](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions), these things come to mind:

- You should use `require` instead of `assert`. Assert is for detecting bugs in the code. Require is for aborting operation on invalid input (your use case).
- Solidity will revert the whole operation, when it encounters `assert` or `require` and nothing will be changed.
- Catching exceptions is not yet possible.
- You could make your function return the accepted value, e.g.:

  ```
  function bid(uint256 _userCode, uint256 _amount) public constant returns (uint256) {

      assert(_userCode> 0);
      assert(_amount> 0);

      winningBid.userCode= _userCode;
      winningBid.amount= _amount;

      var bidData= Bid(_userCode, _amount);
      bids.push(bidData);

      return _amount;
  }
  ```

  It should be possible to tell the difference between a successful call and a failed one, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since the bid function is a transaction (it's changing the blockchain state) you can't read the transaction return value via Nethereum SDK; all you can get is a receipt.